# android jetpack compose bottom bar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is the code of my `BottomAppBar`:

```
BottomAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp),
        ) {
            bottomNavigationItems.forEach { item ->
                NavigationBarItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                    onClick = {
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = item.name, fontSize = 10.sp)
                    },
                    alwaysShowLabel = true,
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp),
                            imageVector = item.icon,
                            contentDescription = item.name
                        )
                    },
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                        Color.White,
                        indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(
                            LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current
                        ),
                        selectedTextColor = Color.White
                    )
                )
            }
        }
```

When I set the height to `56.dp`, the icons and labels overlap, as depicted below. Can you help me to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues with your composable:

### Applying Height Modifier on BottomAppBar()

Please remove te `56.dp` height modifier, which *is limiting NavigationBar's height* causing the label and the icon to overlap.

```
//Remove this modifier
BottomAppBar( modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp))

//Change to Default
BottomAppBar() { ...
```

### Leaving out the NavigationBar Component

Although this is not causing the overlap, you should wrap your `NavigationBarItem` (s) with  **`NavigationBar()`** for the expected MD3 behaviour and appearance.

```
//This is your code
BottomAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp),
        ) {
           // You are missing the NvigationBar() component here
            bottomNavigationItems.forEach { item ->
```

You should wrap it like this:

```
BottomAppBar {
    
            val containerColor = NavigationBarDefaults.containerColor
            val contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.contentColorFor(containerColor)

            //wrap your NavigationBarItems in NavigationBar before iterating
            NavigationBar(containerColor = containerColor, contentColor = contentColor){
            bottomNavigationItems.forEach { item ->
                NavigationBarItem( ...
```

I would also consider removing the **`Modifier.size(30.dp)`** modifier as well as **`colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors( Color.White ..)`** argument but this is entirely up to your design system.

Cheers